# MySQL something wrong

Tags: mysql

Good day, I have problems with this command line:

```
    INSERT INTO oc_idai (name, language_id) 
SELECT 
    name, language_id
FROM 
    oc_product_description 
WHERE 
    (
        name LIKE '%0%' 
        OR name LIKE '%1%' 
        OR name LIKE '%2%' 
        OR name LIKE '%3%' 
        OR name LIKE '%4%' 
        OR name LIKE '%5%' 
        OR name LIKE '%6%' 
        OR name LIKE '%7%' 
        OR name LIKE '%8%' 
        OR name LIKE '%9%'
        AND language_id = '5'
    )
```

This code not working. There are 2 field like **name** and **language_id**. Without one of these fields command is working perfect:

```
    INSERT INTO oc_idai (name) 
SELECT 
    name
FROM 
    oc_product_description 
WHERE 
    (
        name LIKE '%0%' 
        OR name LIKE '%1%' 
        OR name LIKE '%2%' 
        OR name LIKE '%3%' 
        OR name LIKE '%4%' 
        OR name LIKE '%5%' 
        OR name LIKE '%6%' 
        OR name LIKE '%7%' 
        OR name LIKE '%8%' 
        OR name LIKE '%9%'
    )
```

Thanks

Comment: Adding any errors messages to your post for the code that isn't working would be useful.

Comment: How is it not working?  Error? Fails to insert?  Inserts incorrect data?

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional info on the exact nature of 'Not Working', I'm guessing your issue is your where conditional is messed up.  You want everything with a name matching one of the wildcard strings and `language_id = 5`

Change it to:

```
 WHERE 
(
   ( name LIKE '%0%' 
    OR name LIKE '%1%' 
    OR name LIKE '%2%' 
    OR name LIKE '%3%' 
    OR name LIKE '%4%' 
    OR name LIKE '%5%' 
    OR name LIKE '%6%' 
    OR name LIKE '%7%' 
    OR name LIKE '%8%' 
    OR name LIKE '%9%' )
    AND language_id = '5'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ray's helpful observation that your `or` statements should be grouped together -- does your `oc_idai` table actually have a `language_id` field?  In the 'working' query, the language field isn't specified, which implies it's defaulting to either `null` or a schema-specified default. Attempting to `insert` into a field that doesn't exist is a sure way to get an error.

It would help if you put together a fiddle.  Without seeing your schema, we can only make educated guesses.  Here's a working version of the `schema` and `query`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6414/1 Compare it to your own to see where you might be going wrong.